# Reset password on IPMI HP LO 100

Tags: password, ipmi, windows-server-2003-r2

I need to reset password on LO 100. Server HP ProLiant DL120 G6.
If i use lo100cfg.exe from  SmartStart Scripting Toolkit i have error "The Microsoft IPMI WMI provider may not be installed properly.".
WinRM service is running.